# Unpredictable behavior when starting Python queues

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue

I am trying to generate different combinations of queue objects based on input, which is held in the varibale `mode`. When `mode` is set to `'distributed'` the behavior of the program is unpredictable. Sometimes it runs, sometimes it gives me strange errors (`TypeError('cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object')`) but mostly it simply hangs while instantiating `data_queue1`, `data_queue2` and `output_queue`. (See code below.)

The two `data_queue` objects are generated by a class `ModeQueue` which uses a `Manager` to hold the queue(s). `output_queue` is instantiated with the help of a class `QueueManager` which inherits from `BaseManager`. This queue has to be reached from remote machines.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

from lib_a import ModeQueue


class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass


def serve_queue(queue):
    """Start a queue server"""
    QueueManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda: queue)
    m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'key')
    s = m.get_server()
    s.serve_forever()


def distributed_queue():
    """Connect to distributed queue and return object"""
    QueueManager.register('get_queue')
    m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'key')
    m.connect()
    return m.get_queue()


def main():
    mode = 'distributed'
    if mode == 'distributed':
        q = mp.Queue(maxsize=10)
        q_server = mp.Process(target=serve_queue, args=(q,))
        q_server.start()

        data_queue1 = ModeQueue(mode, 20)
        data_queue2 = ModeQueue(mode, 10)
        output_queue = distributed_queue()
    else:
        pass
    # more code...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```py
# lib_a
class ModeQueue:
    def __new__(cls, mode, maxsize):
        from multiprocessing import Manager
        q = Manager().Queue(maxsize=maxsize)
        setattr(q, 'mode', mode)
        setattr(q, 'maxsize', maxsize)
        return q
```

I really do not get where the unpredictable behavior comes from. I have tried finding an error with extensive debug logging, but every time the program freezes no output is written to my log. Can you spot an error or explain why the program does not work as expected?

Comment: I find it really hard to grasp what's happening here. I guess, the indentation is incorrect and `serve_queue` and `distributed_queue` are inside the class but `main` is not, right? I would start clarifying these things and try to rename your `class Queue` inside lib_a, because the class in `multiprocessing` seems to have exactly the same name.

Comment: No, the indentation is not incorrect. `serve_queue` and `distributed_queue` are outside the class `QueueManager`. The code itself is shortened, but all relevant things are there. My class `Queue` returns diffenent objects of a queue based on which `mode` is given. Renaming it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: It's always hard to debug code that can not be executed. That's why the community always asks for complete, executable code snippets. - You will have two various objects in your namespace with the same name, one `Queue` from lib_a and one `Queue` from multiprocessing. So, please just give it a try. Even if it wouldn't resolve your issues, it was still good practice to name them differently.